# Не подгружаются стили

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

Страница логина в Atom красиво выглядит и работает(preview html). Но когда я использую её в проекте и запускаю через intellij idea, то в консоли браузера выдаёт след ошибку `Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost/login' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

Подчёркивается строчка `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`

Оба файла находятся в одной папке

```
-main
--resources
---templates
----login.html
----style.css
```

Файлы:

`login.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html  dir="ltr"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" 
charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form th:action="@{/login}" class="login-form" method="POST">
  <h1>Login</h1>
<div class="txtb">
    <input type="text" th:name="username" >
    <span data-placeholder="Username"></span>
</div>

<div class="txtb">
    <input type="password" th:name="password" >
    <span data-placeholder="Password"></span>
</div>

<input type="submit" class="logbtn" value="Login">

<div class="bottom-text">
    Don't have account? <a href="@{/registration}">Sign up</a>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".txtb input").on("focus",function(){
        $(this).addClass("focus");
    });

    $(".txtb input").on("blur",function(){
        if($(this).val() == "")
            $(this).removeClass("focus");
    });
</script>
```

`style.css`

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: montserrat;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg,#3498db,#8e44ad);
}

.login-form{
  width: 360px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  height: 580px;
  padding: 80px 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.login-form h1{
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.txtb{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #adadad;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.txtb input{
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #333;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0 5px;
  height: 40px;
}

.txtb span::before{
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5px;
  color: #adadad;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: .5s;
}

.txtb span::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(120deg,#3498db,#8e44ad);
  transition: .5s;
}

.focus + span::before{
  top: -5px;
}
.focus + span::after{
  width: 100%;
}

.logbtn{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  background: linear-gradient(120deg,#3498db,#8e44ad,#3498db);
  background-size: 200%;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s;
}

.logbtn:hover{
  background-position: right;
}

.bottom-text{
  margin-top: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

Comment: OpenServer - полет нормальный.
Проблема может быть в том что DOCTYPE объявлен как HTML5, а вот html - как xmlns. Это автоматическое форматирование редактором тем от thymeleaf, или вы сами прописывали?

Comment: сам приписывал, где-то увидел вот, надо убрать? или что-то заменить?

Comment: убрал, терь подписывает тоже самое на ```<!DOCTYPE html>```